# Is it possible to redirect all requests to all files in a specific folder to a specific php-file inside the same folder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I try to secure all files (pdf-files and image-files) in a specific folder by redirecting the requests to a specific php-file in the same folder. The php file checks if a user is logged in and then throws a 404 (not logged in) or returns the requested file.

It's a WordPress installation. When a user uploads a file it will be stored automatically in a folder (inside the uploads-folder) which is named by the id of the specific post. When the user selects the option 'secure' I build automatically another folder in this specific folder called 'secured'. In this 'secured'-folder only users who are logged in will be able to access those files.

I already managed to solve this by placing a rule to the htaccess inside the root directory. But my goal is to redirect it via a htaccess inside this secured-folder. So the goal is to automatically create this 'secured'-folder and the appropriate htaccess php-file inside this folder.

My main problem is the code which I have to place inside the .htaccess file.

I googled a lot - but still didn't found a solution which worked for me. Any help is going to be appreciated.

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1011527)

Comment: From the "sounds" of it, you need some custom script to perform this automation. Without your existing code, I don't think anyone can help you on this matter.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answers anyway. Ivo P understood the question. That was exactly what I was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

The error when not logged in should be 403 "forbidden". That's different from 404 "not found".

let's say the script is named reader.php 
You could place this in the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} !reader.php
RewriteRule ^ reader.php [L]
```

You could add a condition to do this only for exsisting files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

to be placed before the rewriterule line

reader.php could do

```
<?php
    if( !login_check() ) {
       header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
       exit();
    }
    else {
        $file = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $filelocal = ''; // translate $file to something in current dir

       ## give correct header for filetype
       header('Content-Type: application/pdf');

       readfile($filelocal);
    }
```

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, you could accept it